# выбор из нескольких ContextMenu в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Возможно ли иметь несколько `ContextMenu`. в `TreeView` и показывать нужное в зависимости от нажатого `Node`. Скажем, если, `{Binding Name} = "FirstMenu"` показывать одно меню, а если `{Binding Name} = "SecondMenu"` показывать другое

**вот пример моего XAML**

```
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:NavigationTableViewModel}">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                                <Separator />
                                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />


                            </ContextMenu>

                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                        <CheckBox   Focusable="False"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding TableName}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Исправил опечатку в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально, вашу задачу проще всего решить через триггеры:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NavigationTableViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="NavigationRootElement">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <CheckBox   Focusable="False"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding TableName}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="FirstMenu">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" TargetName="NavigationRootElement">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Hello"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Но возможно, вам понадобилось такое из-за неоптимального дизайна программы. Если у вас разные типы контекстного меню, возможно, им должны соответствовать разные типы VM-объектов, и, соответственно, разные `DataTemplate`'ы.
Не слишком ли общим является ваш тип `NavigationTableViewModel`, не нужно ли разбить его на несколько?